# Processes not executing in expected order; fork() and waitpid()

Tags: c, operating-system

I wrote a program that calls `fork()` two times, generating three children and a parent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
    int child1 = fork();
    int child2 = fork();

    // Check for error
    if (child1 < 0 || child2 < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "A fork failed :(\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Parent Process
    if (child1 > 0 && child2 > 0) {
        waitpid(child1, NULL, 0);
        waitpid(child2, NULL, 0);
        printf("I'm the parent\n");
    }
    // Child B -- CONFUSION AREA --
    else if (child1 > 0 && child2 == 0) {
        waitpid(child1, NULL, 0); // Not waiting for process to finish
        printf("I'm child B\n");
    }
    // Child A
    else if (child1 == 0 && child2 > 0) {
        waitpid(child2, NULL, 0);
        printf("I'm child A\n");
    }
    // Child C
    else if (child1 == 0 && child2 == 0) {            
        printf("I'm child C\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to print out

```
I'm child C
I'm child A
I'm child B
I'm the parent
```

but instead, the program prints out

```
I'm child B
I'm child C
I'm child A
I'm the parent
```

I'm confused why child B isn't waiting for `child1`process to finish?

I drew a process tree to try and understand what is going on, and my understanding is that it looks like:

```
/*

         Parent (15543)
         child1 = 15544;
         child2 = 15545
           /       \
          /         \
         /           \
        A (15544)     B (15545)
     child1 = 0;      child1 = 15544;
     child2 = 15546;  child2 = 0;
        /
       /
      /
     C (15546)
     child1 = 0;
     child2 = 0;


*/
```

Comment: You might be interested in [`<threads.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread), C11's standardized threads API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When child B calls `waitpid()` the call fails and returns -1 because the parent is already waiting on child A, and you can't reap a child process twice.

For the behavior you want, you may be better off using inter-process semaphores to synchronize your process execution. Try including `semaphore.h` and take a look at the documentation for `sem_init()`.

Comment: Child B get's an error but not for the reason you say, child B gets an error because it has not started any child.  It has  `child1 > 0` because it inherited the variable value from the parent process when it already initialized from the first `fork()` call... but it is not the parent of that process, so it cannot `wait()` it.  Children connect to their parents but not to other processes, `wait()` only works with actual children.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the first `fork()`, both processes (parent and child) go to the second `fork()` and generate the two other processes you see in the tree.  This is the reason you see a grandchild in the output.  You think there are only two forks executed, so two children are expected, but you have not realized that the second `fork()` is actually executed by two processes: the parent **and the child of the first `fork()` call**.

BTW, the kernel schedules the processes in any order, so you can expect different order in the output lines.  Child B cannot `waitpid()` as it has not started any child (it is the child B in your tree, It has the pid that the parent got for child A, but child A is not its child, so `waitpid()` gives you an error, that you don't examine, and so the printing is done)  You assumed it was a parent because one of the child variables was > 0, but he inherited that variable initialized from its parent, as it didn't execute a `fork()` call.